# Disable Printing Using JS

Tags: javascript, css

It seems that there is no satisfactory JS code available for this.

Have tried the following. It pops up a box and asks for the permission. Can anybody suggest modification in the following code so that printing won't be executed?

```
<script>
if($(".print-mode").is(":hidden")) {
alert("normal mode");
} else {
alert("print mode");
}
</script>
```

Also tried:

```
<style>
.print-mode { display: none;}
@media print {
.print-mode { display: block;}
}
</style>
```

It didn't work.

Comment: What _exactly_ didn't work, what was your aim? Your title and code samples are contradictory: the title says "disable when printed", while your code says "show only when printed".

Comment: Checks for display:[none|block], ignores visible:[true|false]
`$(".print-mode").is(":visible"); `

Comment: I want - disable only when printed

Comment: @Chetan you also do this same using CSS only

Comment: JS don't run in the printer: `.print-mode` is only displayed when printed, and the JS will never fire.

Comment: @Chetan Check my answer. Surely help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control with browser actions

the possible solution is

```
<style type="text/css">
 @media print{
  body {display:none;}
 }
</style>
```

no other stopping mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Please write your code following way :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
if($(".print-mode").is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
} 
else {
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, please add a short description of what your command does and why it solves the initial problem.